# Удаление символа из строки (Python)

Tags: python, delete

столкнулся с проблемой у меня был код:

```
a = "aabbcc"
b = a.replace("a","")
```

и он известно почему удаляет все "a", но можно ли удалить только 1 a(любую), а при отсутствии таковой не выдавать ошибок.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
b = a.replace("a","", 1)
```

Удалит только одно вхождение (первое).

Comment: Может добавить ещё пример с циклом? А то данный ответ ужасен своей магической простатой

Comment: @devnull `There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.`.

Comment: В данном варианте мы скрываем сложность данной операции, пример с циклом хорош как демонстрация реальной сложности операции замены символов в строке

Comment: @devnull в смысле с циклом? Replace засунуть в цикл?

Comment: Нет, приложить код функции replace